# Invoking Page Refresh from Kendo Grid Update

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a Kendo-grid with inline editing Let's call this Grid3.  The Grid is displaying a list of items from a referenced property of the page's view model. When an item on the grid has been saved, I would like to invoke a complete page refresh (or a refresh two other grids, Grid1 and Grid2 on the page).  The reason is that when an items has been updated in the grid, values displayed in other grids are affected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the RequestEnd event.

The Kendo Grid declaration would have something like:

```
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(fi => fi.Id))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Buildings_ReadForecast", "Plan", new {buildingId                               = Model.BuildingID}))
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Events(events => events.RequestEnd("OnRequestEnd_Grid"))
```

Then create the javascript method like:

```
    function OnRequestEnd_Grid(e) {
    if (e.type === "update") {
        var forecastgrid = $('#ForecastGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        var planGrid = $('#PlanGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        planGrid.dataSource.read();
        forecastgrid.dataSource.read();

      }
    }
```

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Call datasource.read() at those grids you want to refresh.

```
$("#grid3").kendoGrid({
   dataSource : dataSource,
   save: function(e) {
    grid1.dataSource.read();
    grid2.dataSource.read();
    }
  }
```

Alternatively place the grid.datasource.read() call into your datasource complete.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    update: { 
                          complete: function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
                                   grid1.dataSource.read();
                                   grid2.dataSource.read();
                                   } 
                            }
                           }
                          });
```

Comment: Bobby_D, thanks. that was helpful in showing me how to refresh the other grids.  However, apparently the Save() event occurs before the Update event is invoked. Any ideas how I might call this event AFTER the Update event is invoked?

Comment: true, you can use complete method on the datasource trasport create/update, this is invoked after the update returns from the server.

Comment: Bobby, that looks like what I need. I'm declaring the grid in Razor as shown below. How would I declare the trasnport/update?):            

   .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                  
                  .Ajax()
                  .Model(model => model.Id(fi => fi.Id))
                  .Read(read => read.Action("Buildings_ReadForecast", "Plan", new {buildingId = Model.BuildingID}))
                  .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                  .Update(update => update.Action("Buildings_ReadForecastEditInline_Update", "Plan") )
                  .PageSize(50)

Comment: Bobby, could never get it going with the trasnport update method. I'd still like to figure that out. Did get it going with the RequestEnd event, however. Thanks for getting me on the right track.